# How can I use lodash groupby or other functions to group following data?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have following data

```
x = [
  [
    {
      key: `col-${1}`,
      value: 'VEH1'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${2}`,
      value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${3}`,
      value: '1 Mar 2016'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${4}`,
      value: '$7'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${5}`,
      value: '$10'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${6}`,
      value: '$12,500'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      key: `col-${1}`,
      value: 'VEH1'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${2}`,
      value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${3}`,
      value: '1 Mar 2016'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${4}`,
      value: '$7'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${5}`,
      value: '$10'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${6}`,
      value: '$12,500'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      key: `col-${1}`,
      value: 'VEH1'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${2}`,
      value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${3}`,
      value: '1 Mar 2016'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${4}`,
      value: '$7'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${5}`,
      value: '$10'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${6}`,
      value: '$12,500'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      key: `col-${1}`,
      value: 'VEH2'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${2}`,
      value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${3}`,
      value: '1 Mar 2016'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${4}`,
      value: '$7'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${5}`,
      value: '$10'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${6}`,
      value: '$12,500'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      key: `col-${1}`,
      value: 'VEH2'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${2}`,
      value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${3}`,
      value: '1 Mar 2016'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${4}`,
      value: '$7'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${5}`,
      value: '$10'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${6}`,
      value: '$12,500'
    }
  ]
];
```

I have this array

```
z = [`col-${1}`,`col-${2}`,`col-${3}`,`col-${4}`,`col-${5}`, `col-${6}`]
```

and I want this data to be grouped as when grouped on `col-${1}`

```
[
  'VEH1' : [
  [
    {
      key: `col-${1}`,
      value: 'VEH1'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${2}`,
      value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${3}`,
      value: '1 Mar 2016'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${4}`,
      value: '$7'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${5}`,
      value: '$10'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${6}`,
      value: '$12,500'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      key: `col-${1}`,
      value: 'VEH1'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${2}`,
      value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${3}`,
      value: '1 Mar 2016'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${4}`,
      value: '$7'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${5}`,
      value: '$10'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${6}`,
      value: '$12,500'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      key: `col-${1}`,
      value: 'VEH1'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${2}`,
      value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${3}`,
      value: '1 Mar 2016'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${4}`,
      value: '$7'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${5}`,
      value: '$10'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${6}`,
      value: '$12,500'
    }
   ]
  ]
  VEH2: [
    [
    {
      key: `col-${1}`,
      value: 'VEH2'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${2}`,
      value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${3}`,
      value: '1 Mar 2016'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${4}`,
      value: '$7'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${5}`,
      value: '$10'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${6}`,
      value: '$12,500'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      key: `col-${1}`,
      value: 'VEH2'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${2}`,
      value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${3}`,
      value: '1 Mar 2016'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${4}`,
      value: '$7'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${5}`,
      value: '$10'
    },
    {
      key: `col-${6}`,
      value: '$12,500'
    }
  ]
    ]
];
```

How can I use lodash groupby or other functions to group this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table for the reference to the wanted group.

```js
var x = [[{ key: `col-${1}`, value: 'VEH1' }, { key: `col-${2}`, value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle' }, { key: `col-${3}`, value: '1 Mar 2016' }, { key: `col-${4}`, value: '$7' }, { key: `col-${5}`, value: '$10' }, { key: `col-${6}`, value: '$12,500' }], [{ key: `col-${1}`, value: 'VEH1' }, { key: `col-${2}`, value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle' }, { key: `col-${3}`, value: '1 Mar 2016' }, { key: `col-${4}`, value: '$7' }, { key: `col-${5}`, value: '$10' }, { key: `col-${6}`, value: '$12,500' }], [{ key: `col-${1}`, value: 'VEH1' }, { key: `col-${2}`, value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle' }, { key: `col-${3}`, value: '1 Mar 2016' }, { key: `col-${4}`, value: '$7' }, { key: `col-${5}`, value: '$10' }, { key: `col-${6}`, value: '$12,500' }], [{ key: `col-${1}`, value: 'VEH2' }, { key: `col-${2}`, value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle' }, { key: `col-${3}`, value: '1 Mar 2016' }, { key: `col-${4}`, value: '$7' }, { key: `col-${5}`, value: '$10' }, { key: `col-${6}`, value: '$12,500' }], [{ key: `col-${1}`, value: 'VEH2' }, { key: `col-${2}`, value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle' }, { key: `col-${3}`, value: '1 Mar 2016' }, { key: `col-${4}`, value: '$7' }, { key: `col-${5}`, value: '$10' }, { key: `col-${6}`, value: '$12,500' }]],
    grouped = {};

x.forEach((hash => a => {
    var key = a[0].value;
    if (!hash[key]) {
        hash[key] = [];
        grouped[key] = hash[key];
    }
    hash[key].push(a);
})(Object.create(null)));

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the `col-${n}` isn't enforced, this would work:

```
var output = _.groupBy(x, arr => _.find(arr, { key: `col-${1}` }).value);
```

Otherwise you could do a lookup first in `z`,

```
var output = _.groupBy(x, _.indexOf(z, `col-${1}`) + '.value');
```

```js
var x = [[{ key: `col-${1}`, value: 'VEH1' }, { key: `col-${2}`, value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle' }, { key: `col-${3}`, value: '1 Mar 2016' }, { key: `col-${4}`, value: '$7' }, { key: `col-${5}`, value: '$10' }, { key: `col-${6}`, value: '$12,500' }], [{ key: `col-${1}`, value: 'VEH1' }, { key: `col-${2}`, value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle' }, { key: `col-${3}`, value: '1 Mar 2016' }, { key: `col-${4}`, value: '$7' }, { key: `col-${5}`, value: '$10' }, { key: `col-${6}`, value: '$12,500' }], [{ key: `col-${1}`, value: 'VEH1' }, { key: `col-${2}`, value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle' }, { key: `col-${3}`, value: '1 Mar 2016' }, { key: `col-${4}`, value: '$7' }, { key: `col-${5}`, value: '$10' }, { key: `col-${6}`, value: '$12,500' }], [{ key: `col-${1}`, value: 'VEH2' }, { key: `col-${2}`, value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle' }, { key: `col-${3}`, value: '1 Mar 2016' }, { key: `col-${4}`, value: '$7' }, { key: `col-${5}`, value: '$10' }, { key: `col-${6}`, value: '$12,500' }], [{ key: `col-${1}`, value: 'VEH2' }, { key: `col-${2}`, value: '300x250 Medium Rectangle' }, { key: `col-${3}`, value: '1 Mar 2016' }, { key: `col-${4}`, value: '$7' }, { key: `col-${5}`, value: '$10' }, { key: `col-${6}`, value: '$12,500' }]],
    z = [`col-${1}`,`col-${2}`,`col-${3}`,`col-${4}`,`col-${5}`, `col-${6}`];

var output = _.groupBy(x, _.indexOf(z, `col-${1}`) + '.value');

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```